# Using ASP.NET to Insert Data into a Database

Tags: sql, asp.net, database

I have a form on my web page that I want posting to my database in the background upon submitting the form. Here is my code:

```
if (Validation.IsValid()) 
{
    // Insert a new user into the database
    var db = Database.Open("StarterSite");

    // Check if user already exists
    var user = db.QuerySingle("SELECT Email FROM UserProfile WHERE LOWER(Email) = LOWER(@0)", email);
    if (user == null) {
        // Insert email into the profile table
        db.Execute("INSERT INTO UserProfile (Email) VALUES (@0)", email);
    }
}
```

This is sample code and I'm trying to interpret it. What's baffling me is that is says `VALUES (@0)`. However, when the form on this page is submitted, it still manages to post the inputted email address though the value says (`@0`) ?

Any clarity would be greatly appreciated!

Regards,

Josh

(P.S, I'm new to ASP.NET)

Comment: By tagging `sql` you can simply check if the user exist or not by applying `unique` _constraint_.  Have a look at the link which gives you detailed information about how to insert records into the database . http://www.onlinebuff.com/article_step-by-step-select-insert-update-and-delete-using-aspnet-c-and-adonet_32.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@0 refers to the first parameter. In your case it is the variable `email` as so;

```
db.Execute("INSERT INTO UserProfile (Email) VALUES (@0)", email);
```

You can insert more than one ordered parameter like this;

```
db.Execute("INSERT INTO UserProfile (Email, SecondParam) VALUES (@0, @1)", @0, @1);
```